# How to remove square brackets adjacent to the hyphen generated by the package "cite"?

Tags: cite-package

I am using the following packages:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

% *** MISC UTILITY PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}
%\usepackage{caption}

% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mediumspace,mediumqspace,Gray,squaren]{SIunits}
\usepackage[citebordercolor={0 1 0}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
% paper title
% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{Fabrication}

% The paper headers
\markboth{JOURNAL OF MICROELECTROMECHANICAL SYSTEMS}%
{ \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Fabrication, Characterization and Modeling of Fully-Integrated Piston-Type Electrodynamic Microactuators}

% make the title area
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
This paper presents 
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{E}{lectrodynamic} 
harvesters\cite{f11:Kulkarni2008,f11:Sari2008,f11:Wang2009,f11:Zhu2010,f11:Peng2011}.
These devices rely.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{f11}


\end{document}
```

After I compile my document I get the following as a part of my resulting .pdf document:
[image]

I want to get rid of the square brackets adjacent to the hyphens, e.g. I want "[9-13]" and not "[9]-[13]", which is the how it is right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it)

Comment: Oh.... I did spend some time trying to get it correct but couldn't. Thanks!

Comment: Try two things: first, load the `cite` package explicitly with the `sort` and `compress` options (as well as the `nobreak` option, if needed): `\usepacakge[sort,compress,nobreak]{cite}`. Second, be sure to load the `hyperref` package *last*. If the problems persist, please augment your code snippets to a full MWE (minimum working example) that duplicates the problem behavior you're encountering. Without such an MWE, it's very difficult (if not impossible) to correctly diagnose and fix the problems.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work... :(
Even after adding nobreak, it didn't work.

Comment: The IEEE use the `[x]-[y]` style, not `[x-y]`, and so the class is deliberately set up to give this output. From your example, I'd assume you are submitting to a journal, in which case altering this here seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extra `[]` pairs are added in here by the `IEEEtran` class. Luckily, it also provides a mechanism to remove them:

```
\renewcommand*{\citepunct}{, } % Was {], [}
\renewcommand*{\citedash}{--}  % Was {]--[}
```

This is documented in the class file only (around line 3100): it does not seem to be in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Actually you might be right about the change being a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely require the use of the `cite` package, `natbib` will let you do this and is in general much more flexible than `cite`.

For example, instead of `\usepackage[sort,compress]{cite}`, try:

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Edit: Note that when changing bibtex packages you sometimes have to run latex and bibtex a couple of times each and use 'q' to skip past some errors.

Comment: there is really `&` in the package options?

Comment: Yes, there is...